# Scipy Optimization Errors: divide by zero encountered

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scientific-computing

I'm confused as to how I am getting a divide by zero error when trying to maximize a function.

```
solution = minimize(objective,x0, method='SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
__main__:36: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
C:\Users\loren\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
C:\Users\loren\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
C:\Users\loren\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1738: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
  cond2 = (x >= self.b) & cond0
__main__:38: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
__main__:40: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
__main__:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
__main__:31: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
__main__:33: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
__main__:36: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
__main__:29: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
__main__:38: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
__main__:31: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
__main__:40: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
__main__:33: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

The code still runs but I don't get anything useful.

```
 fun: nan
 jac: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
 message: 'Iteration limit exceeded'
 nfev: 2212
 nit: 101
 njev: 101
 status: 9
 success: False
 x: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Here is my objective function:

```
def objective(x): #x <-> pl1 pl2 pl3 ph1 ph2 ph3 r prob1 prob2 prob3
    return -x[6]*(x[0]*NL1(x)+x[1]*NL2(x)+x[2]*NL3(x)+x[3]*NH1(x)+x[4]*NH2(x)+x[5]*NH3(x))
```

So I am maximizing over 10 variables.

Here is the form of what the functions are defined as (to not have a ridiculously long objective function):

```
def CDF(x, parameter):
    return expon.cdf(x, scale = 1/parameter)
def NH1(x): #Number of high buyers at location 1
    return 1-CDF((x[3]-x[0])/(x[7]), lambdaB)
def NL1(x): #Number of low buyers at location 1
    return CDF((x[3]-x[0])/x[7], lambdaB) - CDF((s-x[0])/(1+x[7]), lambdaB)
def NS1(x): #Number of sellers at location 1
    return 1- CDF((NH1(x)*(x[3]-x[6])+NL1(x)*(x[0]-x[6]))/(NH1(x) + (1-x[7])*NL1(x)+2*x[7]*NL1(x)), lambdaS)
def constraintGenEq1(x):
    return NS1(x)- NH1(x) -(1+x[7])*NL1(x)
def constraintProbLow1(x):
    x[7] =  (x[3]-x[0])/(dist) 
    return x[7] - (x[3]-x[0])/(dist) 

conGen1= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraintGenEq1}
conGen2= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraintGenEq2}
conGen3= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraintGenEq3}
conProb1= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraintProbLow1}
conProb2= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraintProbLow2}
conProb3= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraintProbLow3}

upper = 150
cons = ([conGen1, conGen2, conGen3, conProb1, conProb2, conProb3])
bnds = ((0,upper),(0,upper),(0,upper),(0,upper),(0,upper),(0,upper),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1))

n=len(bnds)
x0 = np.zeros(n)+0.1
solution = minimize(objective,x0, method='SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
```

I understand if this is kind of dense to read through. But I've tried playing around with the bounds, the constraints, to get it to return something useful, but I haven't had any luck yet. I'm guess where I have division operations in some of my sub-functions I might be running into problems. Lastly, I make certain assumptions about parameters.

```
lambdaB = 1 #Buyer's exponential distribution parameter
lambdaS = 1 #Seller's exponential distribution parameter
dist = 1
s = 4
```

Comment: Add some prints to each of those functions and observe inputs and outputs to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that and update.

Comment: I ran random vectors of size 10, with each random number varying from 0 to 1, and I received no errors, for the functions NS1, NL1, NH1. My outputs all varied from 0 to 1. I did receive some negative numbers so edited NLi functions to return max(output, 0). Here is my code:  `def functest(x, func):
    out = np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        out[i] = func(x[i])
    return out


test = np.random.rand(100,10)
print(functest(test, NS1)) 
print(functest(test, NL1))
print(functest(test, NH1))` Not sure how to format this nicely in comments haha.

Comment: Why don't test it with your real-world data (or what does size 10 mean; you simplified / made the problem smaller?). Even if you can't print those, information is gained. Furthermore: things like ```max(x, 0)``` are not differentiable and the method assumes it's differentiable two times. This will lead to problems eventually.

Comment: Just ran it for the remaining functions, to double check, and they all had similar results. So I think those functions are OK, for now at least.

Comment: I don't have real data, unfortunately. Just trying to build a model to see what the comparative statics would look like, numerically. It doesn't appear to be solvable in a nice way, so I'm trying to do it numerically

Comment: If the result is nan, you will see nan's in these prints at some time. If that's not what you see, you did something wrong.

Comment: Twice differentiability shouldn't be a problem, but you're right, if I have max(x,0) it won't be differentiable at 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165766/discussion-between-user2516746-and-sascha).